# On load document autoscroll not works datatable Primefaces 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

I'm working with `primefaces 5.1` and [jquery scrolltoview](https://github.com/litera/jquery-scrollintoview) , to do  an autoscroll to last row selected on `primeface dataTable`, when the pages is load, but not works, this is the code that I've:

```xhtml
<h:body onload="remoteAutoScroll();">

<ui:composition template="/template/my_template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="metadata">
        <!-- another form here -->
       <h:form id="form">
        <p:growl id="growl" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
                <p:poll interval="300" listener="#{listadoAvaluosBean.actualizarTabla}" update="avaluoTabla" />
                <p:panel id="avaluoTabla"
                    style="width: 100%;margin-bottom:10px;background: transparent;">
                    <p:remoteCommand name="remoteAutoScroll" oncomplete="autoScroll();"  autoRun="true" />
                    <p:dataTable 
                        id="tabla_Avaluos" 
                        var="avaluo"
                        value="#{bean.avaluos}"
                        selection="#{listadoAvaluosBean.avaluo}" rowKey="#{avaluo.id}"
                        selectionMode="single" sortBy="#{avaluo.fechaEstado}"
                        sortOrder="descending"
                        rowStyleClass="#{avaluo.semaforo.estadoSemaforo}"
                        resizableColumns="true" 
                        scrollable="true" 
                        scrollWidth="1400"
                        scrollHeight="250" 
                        scrollRows="10" 
                        liveScroll="true"
                        emptyMessage="No tienes solicitudes"

                        style="clear: right; font-size: 11px !important; margin-top: 5px;">
                        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":form ..somefields" listener="#{bean.mostrarMenuAccion}" />

                           <!--  some columns here -->      
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:panel>
                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"  value="${_csrf.token}" />
        </h:form>
        <!-- more things -->
        <script>
        /*<![CDATA[*/
            function autoScroll(){
                console.log("calling to auto scroll...");
                $(function(){
                    $(function(){
                        $("#form\\:tabla_Avaluos  tr:last").scrollintoview();
                    });
                });

            }
        /*]]>*/
        </script>
    </ui:define>
 </ui:composition>
```

When I load the page looking in the `firebug console`  this print:

[image]

So, the pages never do the auto scroll when I  load the page, so if execute the comand in the `firebug console` the `autoscroll` works.
I'm wondering what am I doing wrong?,

how can I fix it?

Comment: Not sure if I understood the problem. The `autoScroll` function gets called on page load as expected, but does not scroll the table? Is that it? On a semi-related note: why have liveScroll if you want to immediately scroll to the end of the table, thus triggering another page load, so the scroll position becomes somewhere in the middle of the shown two pages?

Comment: yes, you understood right, so if I remove the `live scroll` it works, but what can i do with `on row selection`, when I select a row this "reload the page", because first call my script and after do the primefaces row selection by post, I don't know why call my script when I select a row.